# Is it possible to apply a directive to a component inside another component template?

Tags: angular

I have a ComponentA:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'component-a',
    template: `<span>{{sampleText}}</span>`,
    styles: []
})
export class ComponentA implements OnInit {

    sampleText: string = 'ComponentA';

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

and a directive for ComponentA:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[DirectiveForA]'
})
export class DirectiveForA implements OnInit {

    @Input('customText') customText: string;

    constructor(private componentA: ComponentA) {        
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.componentA.sampleText = this.customText;
    }
}
```

I could apply my directive for it:

```
<component-a>
    <ng-template DirectiveForA customText="injectedText"></ng-template>
</component-a>
```

But then, I have another ComponentB, which have an ComponentA inside:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'component-b',
    template: `<component-a></component-a>`,
    styles: []
})
export class ComponentB implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild(ComponentA, { static: false }) componentA: ComponentA;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

I want to apply the directive to the ComponentA inside it, when using ComponentB like this:

```
<component-b>
    <ng-template DirectiveForA customText="injectedText!"></ng-template>
</component-b>
```

Angular is complaining:

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DirectiveForA -> ComponentA]: 
    StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[DirectiveForA -> ComponentA]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ComponentA!
```

Question: Is there a way for me to make it works? If there isn't, what is the better practice for this?
(In my case, ComponentA is actually a grid, and DirectiveA is template for a certain grid column. ComponentB is actually the grid with an input form. ComponentB is used very frequently but I want to customize a column inside ComponentA.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way using optional injection at last.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[DirectiveForA]'
})
export class DirectiveForA implements OnInit {

    @Input('customText') customText: string;
    private target: ComponentA;

    constructor(@Host() @Optional() public componentA: ComponentA, @Host() @Optional() public componentB: ComponentB) {
        if(componentA){
            this.target = componentA;
        }
        else if(componentB){
            this.target = componentB.componentA;
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if(this.target){
            this.target.sampleText = this.customText;
        }            
    }
}
```